# Design Principles and Patterns in SharePoint

Tags: design-patterns

In context of SharePoint, Can you think of the common scenarios or problems where the enterprise design principles or patterns(from GOF or Martin Fowler) can be applied for better solution design. For e.g.  The *Model-View-Presenter (MVP)* pattern is well-suited to the development of server-side Web Parts and Web pages which provide aggregate views.

Also, It will be helpful if you can provide information on the design patterns applied in Sharepoint product itself. For e.g. The Navigation Providers in SharePoint are based on ASP.NET provider model which is an implementation of *Strategy Pattern*

Comment: I tried to add a comment with the flag, but couldn't. This is an open-ended question, not asking for help with a specific problem. I thought there was another area in the side for asking these sorts of questions.

Answer (score 1):

try to read [SharePoint Guidance from Microsoft Patterns & Practices](http://spg.codeplex.com/releases) and download their framework. They implemented few interesting solutions based on design patterns, for example settings storage based on service locator which detects the level of solution and store settings on different levels of SharePoint: Web app, Site, Web, etc.